# How does Eclipse start weblogic?

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

I'm asking a slightly different question here: How does Eclipse start/stop weblogic when you right click on the server in Eclipse's server pane?

I ask, because this is the only way that I can actually stop and start my server.  The .CMD files that come with weblogic don't work. They never have.

It doesn't help that I'm running my own command-line (JPSoft's TakeCommand/4NT), but even if I go into cmd.exe... The scripts don't work. They never have.  25 years of shell scripting and I can't get them to work. I've spent upwards of 4 hours.

So in the end, I want to just do "Whatever it is that Eclipse does", but Eclipse is not forthright about how it's stopping and starting the server.

Comment: How does the cmd script fail when trying to start weblogic, can you post the error? Is your configuration unique or is this pretty much just a server hosting a war/ear? Could be as simple as it losing `JAVA_HOME` or `JAVA_VENDOR` somewhere along the way.

Comment: I just tried it again, and seemingly got a different error this time:

<unable to get file lock, will retry ...>

It sure would be nice if it told me which file it was trying to get a lock on. Then I could use sysinternals handles.exe to see which process was locking it. I guess that would be too easy?


Also, Trying this left my server in a state where eclipse could not start or stop it. It says "Stopping, Sychronized" in Eclipse, but the stop-weblogic.cmd script isn't even running anymore.